# How to make an image selector to choose an image from the server to use in HTML form

Tags: php, html, image, forms

I have built a blog system where each entry has an associated image file. I have created a php upload for this system and can get everything onto the server. When I write each blog post I have a row in my database which stores the filename of the image, so I could, if I knew the filename already, just type it in.

What I want to do is on my blog post form, instead of being able to type the file name, I want a button to click on which opens a window with all my images in it, then I can click on one and have that filename sent back to the form.

I suppose I could use AJAX to do this but it seems over complicated. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this.

Comment: Whether you are delivering the list of available images to the client via AJAX or have it delivered as part of the form from the beginning does not make much of a difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I suppose what I'm really asking is: How do I pass the filename back from my image window to my form, because the only way I can see to do it involves reloading the form and I'm sure there is an easier way?

Comment: JavaScript can manipulate form fields without reloading.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a little example of how that might work, or point me in the direction of one elsewhere?